# Using selenium XPATH in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on two different sections using XPATH . It works for the first link but it throws an error message

**ElementReferenceException: Message: u'Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up**

```
    driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox").send_keys("watches")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.nav-submit-input").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.refinementNodeChildren > li > a >span.childRefinementLink").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='ref_199497031']/li[4]/a/span[text()='Chronograph']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='ref_199493031']/li[2]/a/span[text()=\"Men's\"]").click()
```

In the above code

The program finds the first element by XPATH "Chronograph" work fine but the second one "Men's"doesn't work..

If i swap the last two lines..

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='ref_199493031']/li[2]/a/span[text()=\"Men's\"]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='ref_199497031']/li[4]/a/span[text()='Chronograph']").click()
```

In this case, the first element by XPATH "Men's" work fine but the second one "Chronograph"doesn't work

I am not sure if its not exiting the previous xpath to find the new one!! Is there a way to exit XPATH so that i can find other elements in the page?

Comment: seems you have answer in your error message !! Try to check for Chronograph element using Inspect Element from Chrome after clicking on Men's..

Comment: can you provide URL on which you are using this xpaths ?

Comment: What does the click do?  Does it navigate you to another page?  If the page changes when you click on it, then its very likely that the javascript is doing stuff while you are doing your second click.  You will have to wait until the javascript finishes to click on the second element.

Comment: The click action is changing dom in some way? Can you post the source code?